# Iteratively check function presence at compile time

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, boost-serialization

I have a question regarding one issue that I am facing right now.
In C++ I have created an helper able to detect if the template parameter of a given template method implements a `serialize` method (boost serialization implementation).
The helper works flawlessly with most of the classes I can throw at it, but I want to extend its functionality as follows.

Lets suppose I have a `Foo` class which has the serialize method.
I wish I can pass it any nested supported container `vector<list<array<Foo,8>>>`, given that `vector`, `list` and `array` provide the `serialize` method.

How can I iteratively go deeper in contained types down to a type not implementing the `value_type` member?

Thank you in advance

Here you get my current solution:

```
namespace check
{
///A set of classes and struct to be sure the serialised object is either trivial or implementing custom serialize
template <class Type, class Archive, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_class<Type>::value>::type>
class is_boost_serializable
{
 private:
  struct TypeOverloader {
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version) {}
  };
  struct TypeExt : public Type, public TypeOverloader {
  };
  template <typename T, T t>
  class DeductionHelper
  {
  };

  class True
  {
    char m;
  };
  class False
  {
    True m[2];
  };

  template <typename TestType>
  static False deduce(TestType*, DeductionHelper<void (TypeOverloader::*)(), &TestType::serialize>* = 0);
  static True deduce(...);

 public:
  static const bool value = (sizeof(True) == sizeof(deduce((TypeExt*)(0))));
};
} // namespace check
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename...>
using void_t = void;

template <typename Type, typename Archive, typename = void_t<>>
struct is_boost_serializable : std::false_type {};

template <typename Type, typename Archive>
struct is_boost_serializable<Type, Archive,
    void_t<decltype(std::declval<Type&>().serialize(std::declval<Archive&>(), 0))>>
    : std::true_type {};

template <typename Type, typename Archive, typename = void_t<>>
struct nested_is_boost_serializable
    : is_boost_serializable<Type, Archive> {};

template <typename Type, typename Archive>
struct nested_is_boost_serializable<Type, Archive, void_t<typename Type::value_type>>
    : nested_is_boost_serializable<typename Type::value_type, Archive> {};
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5f4ed9212a27b9f)

Comment: Thank you for your solution that worked well for me. I have added some features such as support for base types (which are trivially serializable). I post my extended solution down as an additional answer.

Comment: @jetstream you are welcome. your original solution used a mix of old techniques that with C++11 were superseded with *expression SFINAE*. recursive instantiation of the trait is a common technique on the other hand. this code can be shortened even more with C++2a's detection idiom

Comment: I am trying to move my first steps in SFINAE ad I learned something more from your post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Following Piotr awesome suggestion I have extended his solution in order to be compatible also with boost trivially serialisable types (int, char, double...).

Here after my customised solution.

Cheers and thanks!

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/is_bitwise_serializable.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/array.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/list.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/set.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>

struct Arc
{
};

struct Foo
{
    int pippo = 0;

    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar &pippo;
    }
};

struct Bar
{
};

template <typename...>
using void_t = void;

template <typename Type, typename Archive = boost::archive::binary_oarchive, typename = void_t<>>
struct is_boost_serializable_base : std::false_type
{
};

template <class Type, typename Archive>
struct is_boost_serializable_base<Type, Archive,
                                  void_t<decltype(std::declval<Type &>().serialize(std::declval<Archive &>(), 0))>>
    : std::true_type
{
};

template <typename Type, typename Archive>
struct is_boost_serializable_base<Type, Archive,
                                  typename std::enable_if<boost::serialization::is_bitwise_serializable<Type>::value>::type>
    : std::true_type
{
};

template <typename Type, typename Archive = boost::archive::binary_oarchive, typename = void_t<>>
struct is_boost_serializable
    : is_boost_serializable_base<Type, Archive>
{
};

template <typename Type, typename Archive>
struct is_boost_serializable<Type, Archive, void_t<typename Type::value_type>>
    : is_boost_serializable<typename Type::value_type, Archive>
{
};

template <typename Type>
struct is_boost_serializable<Type, boost::archive::binary_oarchive, void_t<typename Type::value_type>>
    : is_boost_serializable<typename Type::value_type, boost::archive::binary_oarchive>
{
};

int main()
{
    static_assert(is_boost_serializable<Foo, Arc>::value, "!");
    static_assert(is_boost_serializable<std::vector<std::list<std::array<Foo, 8>>>, Arc>::value, "!");
    static_assert(is_boost_serializable<std::vector<std::list<std::array<int, 8>>>, Arc>::value, "!");
    static_assert(not is_boost_serializable<std::vector<std::list<std::array<Bar, 8>>>, Arc>::value, "!");
}
```